# Enabling blocks in an install profile

Tags: 7, blocks, theming, distributions

I'm creating an install profile and I just can't seem to get my blocks enabled.

When I check the database after using the code below in my install function it puts the records in the block table, but the status is set to 0 and the region detail isn't inserted.

I'm using code from other install profiles and I can't see why mine isn't working - works fine on things like the erecruiter profile, the omega profile, but whenever I try it never works! Anyone experienced similar?

```
// Enable some standard blocks.
$default_theme = 'mytheme';
$admin_theme = 'seven';
$values = array(
array(
  'module' => 'system',
  'delta' => 'main',
  'theme' => $default_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'content',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'node',
  'delta' => 'recent',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 10,
  'region' => 'dashboard_main',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'user',
  'delta' => 'login',
  'theme' => $default_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'sidebar_first',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'system',
  'delta' => 'navigation',
  'theme' => $default_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'sidebar_first',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'system',
  'delta' => 'powered-by',
  'theme' => $default_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 10,
  'region' => 'footer',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'system',
  'delta' => 'help',
  'theme' => $default_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'help',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'system',
  'delta' => 'main',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'content',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'system',
  'delta' => 'help',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'help',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'user',
  'delta' => 'login',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 10,
  'region' => 'content',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
),
array(
  'module' => 'user',
  'delta' => 'new',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'dashboard_sidebar',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
 ),
);
$query = db_insert('block')->fields(array('module', 'delta', 'theme', 'status', 'weight', 'region', 'pages', 'cache'));
foreach ($values as $record) {
  $query->values($record);
}
$query->execute();
```

Comment: You code looks to be correct, from what I can tell, which leads me to be that there is some other factor. Is your mytheme theme getting set as the default theme and enabled correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the Profiler library to drive your installation profile? If so, there's a "feature" in the 7.x-2.0-beta1 release that causes this behavior. In short, [there's some legacy code that disables all blocks](http://drupal.org/node/1165672) in the database upon installation.

If you're using the Profiler module, upgrade to the latest development snapshot to get the fix.